# Google maps zoom adjustment at initialize?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have 2 problems with the code below and I’ll post them separately.  I have reduced the code down to a reasonable size for this forum hopefully.  The problem here is that when I first go to the page (or reload the page) and click the go button the map initializes and the zoom is adjusted at the end with setZoom() if it’s too high.  When I click the go button again this adjustment no longer happens.  I’ve tried adding a different event listener and then removing/clearing it but that doesn’t seem work either.  How do I set this up as I don’t want to refresh the page all the time?  This map will ultimately be driven by selection menu.

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat = -31.953;
var lon = 115.853;
var address = "200 St George's Terrace, Perth, WA, 6000";

function initialize() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var addrLatLon = results[0].geometry.location;

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: addrLatLon,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                bounds.extend(addrLatLon);
                var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: addrLatLon,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Address Location',
                    draggable: true
                });

                if (lat != 0 && lon != 0) {
                    var LatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                    bounds.extend(LatLon);
                    var latlonMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: LatLon,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Lat/Lon Location'
                    });
                }

                map.fitBounds(bounds);

                // Place control div
                var control = document.getElementById('map-control');
                control.style.display = 'block';
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

                // Update current position info.
                updateMarkerPosition(addrLatLon);

                // Add dragging event listener.
                google.maps.event.addListener(addrMarker, 'drag', function() {
                    updateMarkerPosition(addrMarker.getPosition());
                });

                // Check zoom and set accordingly
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                    if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16);
                });

            } else {
                alert('No result found for address.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

function updateMarkerPosition(p) {
    document.getElementById('map-control').innerHTML = [
        p.lat(),
        p.lng()
    ].join(', ');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mapchk").click(function() {
        initialize();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-control" style="border:thin solid #000;"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:30px;height:500px;width:600px;border:thin solid #000;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="mapchk" id="mapchk" value="Go"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are redrawing the map with every time you click `go` button. That's why `zoom_changed` event is never being called.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot wrong with your code. The first issue is that you're generating the map every time you click `go`. So initialise all of the things you need upfront in a separate function, and then only run the code you need when you click the button.

```
#map-control { position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 400px; height: 20px; text-align: center; background-color: white;}

var lat = -31.953;
var lon = 115.853;
var address = "200 St George's Terrace, Perth, WA, 6000";
var bounds, map, geocoder, control;

function init() {
    var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], mapOptions);
    control = $('#map-control').css({
        left: $('#map-canvas').position().left,
        width: $('#map-canvas').outerWidth(),
        top: $('#map-canvas').position().top + $('#map-canvas').outerHeight() - 24,
    });
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
```

That's what init does. But notice a couple of other things. I've used a positioned div to hold the latitude and longitude coords, rather than a control. The problem with a control is as soon as you add it to a map, it gets removed from the DOM. That's why you got an error the second time you tried to run `updateMarkerPosition`: the control simply wasn't there.

```
function run() {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
            var latLngList = [];
                var addrLatLon = results[0].geometry.location;
                latLngList.push(addrLatLon);
                var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: addrLatLon,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Address Location',
                    draggable: true
                });
                if (lat != 0 && lon != 0) {
                    var LatLon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
                    var latlonMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: LatLon,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Lat/Lon Location'
                    });
                    latLngList.push(LatLon);
                }
                for (i = 0, l = latLngList.length; i < l; i++) {
                    bounds.extend(latLngList[i]);
                }
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                updateMarkerPosition(addrLatLon);
                google.maps.event.addListener(addrMarker, 'drag', function() {
                    updateMarkerPosition(addrMarker.getPosition());
                });
               if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16);
            } else {
                alert('No result found for address.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

There was also an issue with `bounds` that I've corrected that was probably causing some problems, and I've removed the event that's called when the zoom level changes as I couldn't work out what you were trying to do there.

```
function updateMarkerPosition(p) {
    $('#map-control').html([
        p.lat(),
        p.lng()
    ].join(', '));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mapchk").click(function() {
        init();
        run();
    });
});
```

Hopefully this will do what you want.

Comment: Excellent.  I've split the init() and run() functions onto 2 different buttons and played with adding different coordinates and addresses to see what happens.  This has helped my understanding significantly.  Is making bounds, map, geocoder and control global variables critical to making this work?  I'm guessing it is.